# High system load due to .vscode-server processes

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, load, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

on our Linux servers we observe quite some `.vscode-server` processes (basically `$PREFIX/.vscode-server/bin/$ID/node`) from developers using the vscode-remote-ssh extension.  Unfortunately these processes put considerable load onto the systems, due to waiting for I/O (state "D"/uninterruptible sleep).

All affected filesystems are NFS (v3 and v4.0) mounted shares.  There's nothing we can do on the fileserver end.

- Why exactly do these processes require so much I/O? The `.vscode-server` processes sometimes generate more load than some of the data processings on these servers.
- Is this a known problem of `vscode-remote-ssh` and/or is there a way to solve or work around this I/O problem?

Comment: I have the same issue but on my laptop. I use WSL Ubuntu on Windows 11 and VS Code works remotely with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

It helped me:

**First**

I thought that some extension in vscode may cause this problem, and I deleted several of the which I never used. Some ssh remote connection but not main that can connect vscode by ssh to my server. It decrease my cpu usage by 25%.

**Second**

I notice that vscode always tells me about - I can't read all files on server, so I thought that vscode trying to do that on a cycle and can't stop, just trying and trying.

So I did this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

It helped me completely.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [information](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-up-the-vs-code-server-on-the-remote) from the VS Code's documentation and it helped me to solve the problem. I used the following commands:

```
# Kill server processes
kill -9 `ps aux | grep vscode-server | grep USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

You as well can delete files, if they took up too much space. **! But be careful !**, clearing the files will erase information about VS Code extensions, which may be useful.

```
# Delete related files and folder
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-server # Or ~/.vscode-server-insiders
```

Comment: I don't quite follow you kill command. Why are the 'grep' commands escaped? and `USER` should be `$USER`.  
  
Additionally, SIGHUP is probably better than SIGKILL to allow the processes to exit cleanly:  
   
    kill -s SIGHUP `ps aux | grep \$USER | grep -v grep | grep vscode-server | awk '{print \$2}'`

Comment: kill -s SIGHUP $(ps aux | grep \$USER | grep -v grep | grep vscode-server | awk '{print \$2}')

Comment: I can't get the comment formatting to work with the backticks in the code block, so I changed it to use $()

Comment: @FlakRat I don't understand where these backslashes came from. Edited. Thank you.